# Factors influencing existence of groundwater

Tags: hydrology, groundwater

I'm going to use RS/GIS techniques and an Analytic Hierarchy Process (AHP)  to identify potential groundwater zones , but first I need to identify all factors influencing the existence of groundwater. So far I have these layers, Rainfall, slope, lineament density, drainage density, lulc, geology, soil, topographic wetness index. I want to know what else can influence the existence of groundwater?

Comment: Having a good conceptual model of your potential groundwater system will help you identify the key datasets. e.g. are you looking at fracture flow or intergranular flow - confined or unconfined etc.  In addition 'Existence' of groundwater is rarely a useful question, compared to the identification of recharge areas, flow pathways and discharge areas, and associated aquifer properties.